# PyQt5 - How to pass link through method connected to QLabel's linkActivated signal?

Tags: python, pyqt5

While I am able to successfully implement a connection to a method from the linkActivated listener of my QTableWidget's QLabel, I can't figure out how to pass the link through the method despite the fact that the documentation says that the link is obtainable.

> linkActivated(const QString &link)

What I can't figure out is how to get that '&link' data in Python. There are three questionmarks (???) in the place where I am trying to pass the link.

```
def test(i = 1)
    qtbl = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
    qtbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 870, 30))
    qtbl.setObjectName("qtbl%s" % i )
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widgetText = QtWidgets.QLabel("<a href=\"www.foo.com\"><font color=\"#F2F299\">foo</font></a><a href=\"www.foo.com\"><font color=\"#F299F2\">bar</font></a>")
    widgetLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    widgetLayout.addWidget(widgetText)
    widgetLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetFixedSize)
    widget.setLayout(widgetLayout)

    widgetText.linkActivated.connect(lambda ix, sf = self, lk = ??? : linkListener(sf, lk))
    qtbl.setCellWidget(0, 0, widget)

def linkListener(self, link):
    print(link)
```

Design Class:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(896, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrDocumentTables = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrDocumentTables.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 871, 541))
        self.scrDocumentTables.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrDocumentTables.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrDocumentTables.setObjectName("scrDocumentTables")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 869, 539))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents_2")
        self.scrDocumentTables.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 896, 17))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I realise this is probably a newb question, but how do I get that '&link' data?

Comment: Use `widgetText.linkActivated.connect(lambda lk, sf = self : linkListener(sf, lk))`

Comment: Use `widgetText.linkActivated.connect(self.linkListener)`

Comment: @eyllanesc Using lambda lk as the link worked, thanks!

Comment: Why do you ask the same question with 2 accounts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046515/how-to-get-link-when-doing-qlabel-linkactivated-connect